# Is there any place I can download historical traffic data?

Tags: historical

Looking for historical traffic data, if possible in a GIS format. Looking for the country of India, if not anything larger. I know that's big but that's the scope of our study, so yeah. Any kind of help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest some websites that provided different traffic information.
 I hope they contain your request.
https://www.travelmidwest.com/lmiga/home.jsp 
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/PEMS-SF# 
https://data.austintexas.gov/browse?tags=transportation 
http://pems.dot.ca.gov/ 
and
https://data.world/datasets/traffic-volume  

If you have to send a request: 
https://www.markham.ca/wps/portal/home/onlineservices/trafficdatarequest 
Special native area :
https://www.141.ir/trafficcounterfiles